# Class CreateBlobOptions not found

Tags: php, azure, azure-cdn

i'm trying to use azure cdn service, and i got this error in my following code, i've searched everywhere but i didn't find CreateBlobOption class over internet or in official azure git respiratory or in their website also, help me, i'm stuck with it

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;


    $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=my_key';
    $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
    $content = fopen('my_file.jpg','r');
    $blob_name = 'my_file.jpg';
    $options = new CreateBlobOptions();
    $options->setBlobContentType('image/jpeg');
    try
    {
        $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("images", $blob_name, $content,$options);
    }
    catch(ServiceException $e)
    {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find `CreateBlobOptions` class under `WindowsAzure\Blob\Models` folder in your SDK installation. Link to source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/CreateBlobOptions.php.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the class lies:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/CreateBlobOptions.php